# How to inject HTML, CSS and jQuery in realtime to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to build a HTML, CSS and jQuery (not just JavaScript) editor, and show the rendered content in an iFrame. Although adding HTML, CSS part is easy, I am unable to execute the JavaScript part.

```
var html = ""; // HTML code
var content = $("#preview").contents().find("body"); // iframe id is 'preview'
content.html(html);

var cssLink = "<style>" + csVal + "</style>"; // cssVal contains css code
var head = $("#preview").contents().find("head");
head.append(cssLink);

var js ='<script>'+jsEditor()+'<\/script>' ; 

// following part is not working
var content = $('#preview').contents();
$content.find('head').append('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"><\/script>' );             
$content.find('body').append(js );
```

I am able to execute to core JavaScript using window.eval(), however it is not working for any JS library included, e.g. jQuery etc.

Comment: Don't use iframes unless it's to include some external content. Anyway, why using this approach? Just add it to the html file or whatever you're doing without this mix-approach.

Comment: @Jonast92 I think he's trying to make a real-time editor similar to JSFiddle/jsbin etc so therefore he cannot specify it in advance in the html file.

Comment: The duplicate question linked no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

I think your only problem here is your variable naming:

```
var content = $('#preview').contents();
$content.find('head').append('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"><\/script>' );             
$content.find('body').append(js );
```

should be ($content ==> content)

```
var content = $('#preview').contents();
content.find('head').append('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"><\/script>' );             
content.find('body').append(js );
```

I modified your script slightly but only to provide some pre-canned values for `html`, `csVal` and a result from `jsEditor()`.

This worked for me in Chrome, Safari & Firefox running off a server on localhost:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Look at your new iFrame</div>
        <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </body>
</html>
```

Code (also in the html body):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = "<div>Hello from iframe</div>"; // HTML code
    var content = $("#preview").contents().find("body"); // iframe id is 'preview'

    content.html(html);

    var csVal = "div { color: red; font-size: 40px;}";
    var cssLink = "<style>" + csVal + "</style>"; // cssVal contains css code
    var head = $("#preview").contents().find("head");
    head.append(cssLink);

    var jsCode = "alert('you are in the iframe')";

    var js ='<script>'+jsCode+'<\/script>' ; 

    // following part is not working
    var content = $('#preview').contents();
    content.find('head').append('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"><\/script>' );             
    content.find('body').append(js );
});
```

Resulting source in the iFrame:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                color: red;
                font-size: 40px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Hello from iframe</div>
        <script>
            alert('you are in the iframe')
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try my example as is?  I works for me in chrome loading the page off the file system. (No webserver)

Comment: @Gandalf That example also works in chrome, latest safari beta and firefox in a web server running off localhost. I'll update the answer with the html as well.

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working. Would it be possible for you to provide a jsBin or jsFiddle?